# Passing parameters to a script

Tags: shell, unix, parameters

How can I pass parameters to a script like that:

```
scriptname.ksh -p param1 -n param2
```

I mean how can I tell my script to work with two parameters defined by `-p` and `-n` characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while getopts ":p:n:" Option; do
  case $Option in
    p)
      # do stuff
      # to access param1, use variable $OPTARG
      ;;
    n)
      # do stuff
      # $OPTARG again to access param2
      ;;
    \?)
      # default
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
```

In the first argument to `getopts`:

- leading `:` supresses `getopts`'s own internal error reporting
- letters indicate options
- if a letter is followed by a `:`, it means it expects an $OPTARG

[more information](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)

getopts provides faculties for changing the name of the option argument variable.

note that getopts cannot process "long-form" arguments (`--help` etc.)

Comment: I would add a "default" branch to the case statement: `?) error "invalid option: -$OPTARG"; show_help; exit 1 ;;`